# Cordova plugin development - adding aar

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, android-studio, aar

I am new to the cordova plugin development stuff.
I want to write a plugin which is able to open a new android activty and showing some advertisement.

So I followed a simple tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/quickstart). That works very well and as expected.

Next step is to include this Android Studio Gradle project to my plugin.

My first try: Adding the gradle project to a subfolder of my cordova plugin and adding the following line to the plugin.xml file:

```
<framework src="libs/Broper/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

also I tried:

```
<framework src="libs/Broper/app/build.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

doesn't work. So I can't import the classes of that android studio project to my plugin java files.

Then a better solution (I thought so) is to add an AAR instead. But there I don't even have a clue what to do to add that AAR in my cordova plugin.

So, the question is: How do I add an android studio project (or library) to my cordova plugin the right way?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Here's what I've done to use a gradle reference with a Cordova plugin, I think this might help you.

Global structure :

```
pluginFolder/
  build-extras.gradle
  plugin.xml
  yourDirContainingYourAAR/
  src/
    android/
      yourFile.gradle
      myPlugin.java
```

Put your library, say `foo.aar`, in the `yourDirContainingYourAAR` directory (create it if needed)

- In the `plugin.xml` file :

  ```
  <platform name="android">
      <!-- your configuration elements, references, source files, etc... -->

      <framework src="src/android/yourFile.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />

      <resource-file src="yourDirContainingYourAAR/foo.aar" target="libs/foo.aar" />
  </platform>
  ```
- In the gradle file `yourFile.gradle` :

  ```
  repositories{    
    jcenter()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
     }
  }

  dependencies {
     compile(name:'foo', ext:'aar')
  }

  android {
    packagingOptions {
      exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
      exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
  }
  ```
- In the **root folder** of your plugin (same level as `plugin.xml` ) create a `build-extras.gradle`.
  If needed, add or remove `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` according to  your project needs :

  ```
  android {
      defaultConfig {
          minSdkVersion 16
          targetSdkVersion 22
      }

     packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
         exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Is this for a AAR or a normal Android Studio Project? And what else is in the src/android dir? the whole gradl android Studio Project? Or the AAR? or thje "app" dir from the Android Studio Project?

Comment: src/android dir constains all things necessary for your plugin. You can put a whole gradle Android Studio project

Comment: That answer confuses me a bit more. Cause if i put my Android Studio Project in there, i will orverwirte the build.gradle from that one with the "empty" one you providet. so i dont see the connection between the ASP and my plugin. Or is just dont understand somthething right.

Comment: You are right, I forgot some elements. I'll edit my answer ASAP

Comment: okay you changes helping. but one more question: in the build.gradle file dir "dirs" param is it relative to the gradlefile? is it "dirs '.' or dirs "" if the aar is in the same dir as the gradle file?

Comment: finaly it works! one thing we forgotin the plugin config.xml:
<resource-file src="libs/foo.aar" target="libs/foo.aar" />

Comment: I can confirm that the <resource-file src="libs/foo.aar" target="libs/foo.aar" /> is also required. Note also that the flatDir path is the target path of that resrouce and not the src path.

Comment: Thanks for pointing the missing resource-file, I've updated answer. I hope this will save some people from troubles :-)

Comment: Thanks @Niko , you save my date.

Comment: @Niko yourFile.gradle is this copied to the android project or merged with project level gradle file?

Comment: @Niko how is `build-extras.gradle` copied from the plugin root folder to the   android platform folder if it's not explicitly referenced in the `plugin.xml`? Does Cordova implicitly look for this file and deploy it `platforms/android`? And if so, where does it copy it to?

Comment: In my case i have created .aar file and successfully integrated. But I'm getting error in .aar 's style attr error like ..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml :9: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. ..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml :13:21-32: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. but resources are found in my project

Comment: I am still having an issue  ERROR: Failed to resolve: :apprelease:
Affected Modules: app

Answer (score 22):

There has to be a slight modification to [Niko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757738/2579248)

When gradle runs the compilation using [Niko's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757738/2579248), it searches for the libs in `app/libs` which is not present in the project (it does in the standard Android Studio project, but in Cordova Android project structure the libs folder is different). However the plugin copies the aar library to `app/src/main/libs` which can make us think it is copying the aar to `app/libs`

`<resource-file src="yourDirContainingYourAAR/foo.aar" target="libs/foo.aar" />`

Hence the gradle file should be

```
repositories{    
 jcenter()
   flatDir {
     dirs 'src/main/libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
  compile(name:'foo', ext:'aar')
}

android {
 packagingOptions {
  exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
  exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
 }
}
```

This will give you a successful compilation of the app

Cheers!!

Comment: In my case i have created .aar file and successfully integrated. But I'm getting error in .aar 's style attr error like ..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml :9: AAPT: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar'. ..\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values\values.xml :13:21-32: AAPT: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'colorAccent'. but resources are found in my project

Comment: @AravindhanGs were you able to solve the error you got? I'm getting a similar error.

Comment: @executor Finally i solved the above error by removing all colors and styles file in .aar and use all your class as Activity instead of AppCompatActivity.
Use theme as android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar" in manifest

Comment: I am having an issue ERROR: Failed to resolve: :apprelease:
Affected Modules: app

Comment: This was required after upgrading to Cordova 9 for me.  Was fine without `src/main` for some reason on Cordova 8

Answer (score 1):

Okay, because there are multiple answers here and none of them fully capture everything that needs to be done, I'm going to create an all inclusive answer. Hopefully it will save people some time and frustration.

It's pretty straight forward, you just have to update `plugin.xml` to state where the .aar file should go inside the android project. Then you have to tell gradle where to look for it.

So I have this directory structure (you can use a different one):

```
-- my-plugin/
   |-- deps/
       |-- some-dependency.aar
   |-- src/
       |-- MyPlugin.java
   |-- www/
       |-- plugin.js
   |-- package.json
   |-- plugin-settings.gradle
   |-- plugin.xml
```

#### Step 1

The first step is to tell cordova where to put the .aar file. You do that by including a line in `plugin.xml`:

```
<resource-file src="deps/some-dependency.aar" target="libs/some-dependency.aar" />
```

That will grab the file from the `deps` folder in your source and stick it into the the `platforms/android/app/src/main/libs/` folder in the resulting android project. Apparently the `target` path is relative to the `platforms/android/app/src/main` folder. Not sure if that can be changed.

Before moving on to step 2, it might be a good idea to run `cordova build android` to verify that the .aar file is being copied to the right place.

#### Step 2

So once that's working the next step is to tell gradle where the file is so it can resolve it correctly during the build. You do that by creating your own .gradle file that will be merged with the main gradle file that cordova creates for you.

Create a file called `plugin-settings.gradle` and put the following line in it:

```
repositories{    
  flatDir {
      dirs 'src/main/libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile(name:'some-dependency', ext:'aar')
}
```

Note that the line `dirs 'src/main/libs'` tells gradle where to look for the .aar file. It does not dictate where cordova puts that file, just where gradle looks for it. Also note that the path is relative to the `platforms/android/app/` folder and that the resulting path must match where cordova is putting the .aar file.

So in my `plugin.xml` file I have `target="libs/some-dependency.aar"` therefore in my `plugin-settings.gradle` file I have `dirs 'src/main/libs'`. If these don't line up you're going to get build errors.

#### Step 3

Now tell your plugin to use the .gradle file:

```
<framework src="plugin-settings.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
```

Note that you can put the `pllugin-settings.gradle` file where ever you want and you can call it whatever you want. Just make sure the `<framework>` entry matches.

#### Yay

That's pretty much it. You should be able to build and run your app at this point. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If all the above fails just like it did to me... Try these alteration:

1. Use `lib-file` instead of `resource-file`

```xml
<lib-file src="yourDirContainingYourAAR/foo.aar"/>
```

2. Use `implementation` instead of `compile`

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
}
```

Ref: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/add-aar-file-to-cordova-plugin/168675/3