# How to integrate .aar file within the plugin development project (not able to access the packages)

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, cordova-plugins

**I'm developing a cordova plugin and want to integrate previously developed sdk (.aar) file with it.**
I have tried lot of tutorials that i found from stackoverflow or elsewhere. But nothing is working.
Main problem that i'm facing is
 *►►Not able to access the class files of sdk (.aar) file►►*

Reference of my implementation : [Cordova plugin development - adding aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757208/cordova-plugin-development-adding-aar)
  (Answer by [Niko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3096087/niko))

Answer (score 1):

I remember having to do a few changes to the answers found in SO to make it work, but I don't remember what was the issue with the original answers, so here's what I have in my plugin, hope it can help you.

plugin.xml :

```
    <platform name="android">   
             ...
             ...

            <framework src="src/android/mygraddlefile.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />
            <resource-file src="src/android/libs/myaarfile.aar" target="libs/myaarfile.aar" />
             ...
             ...
<platform>
```

mygraddlefile.gradle (src/android/mygraddlefile.gradle in the plugin):

```
repositories{    
  mavenCentral()
  flatDir{
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile(name:'myaarfile', ext:'aar')
}

android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  }
}
```

And I have the aar file in src/android/libs/myaarfile.aar in the plugin.