# How to include Multiple AAR files in custom Cordova Plugin?

Tags: android, cordova, android-gradle-plugin, cordova-plugins

I am new to the Cordova Development. I need to write a custom plugin which is referring two .aar files. I am able to add the first .aar file to the plugin however I am having some doubts for adding the second .aar file.

Can I add the second .aar file in the same custom plugin ? or Do I need to create another custom plugin for using the other .aar file ?

Below is the SO question that helped me to add the first .aar file in the plugin:
[Cordova plugin development - adding aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757208/cordova-plugin-development-adding-aar)

Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://github.com/movintracks/cordova-plugin/blob/master/plugin.xml#L25

Comment: Thanks @DaveAlden for your quick response. I am referring to the github link shared from you.