# How to create Cordova Plugin Template?

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, android-library, aar

I am a newbie in creating cordova plugin or apps. I have an android native library i.e. an aar file which I need to make a cordova plugin from. I have read many articles about creating such a folder structure as below:

```
pluginFolder/
  build-extras.gradle
  plugin.xml
  yourDirContainingYourAAR/
  src/
    android/
      yourFile.gradle
      myPlugin.java
```

I followed this answer for folder structure and put all necessary files in respective folders >> [Cordova plugin development - adding aar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30757738/3879456)

In the plugin.xml file :

```
<framework src="src/android/yourFile.gradle" custom="true" type="gradleReference" />

<resource-file src="yourDirContainingYourAAR/mylib.aar" target="libs/mylib.aar" />
```

In the gradle file yourFile.gradle :

```
repositories{    
  jcenter()
  flatDir {
      dirs 'libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
   compile(name:'mylib', ext:'aar')
}

android {
  packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
  }
}
```

build-extras.gradle :

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
    }

   packagingOptions {
       exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
       exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
   }
}
```

I created folder structure for cordova app using cordova CLI tool and opened the app in Android Studio. I tried making the above folder structure for plugin as it is in Android Studio, but the problem is my gradle files are not getting synced because of that I am not able to access APIs of my aar.

Comment: post the plugin.xml and gradle files content you are using, if not it's impossible to know what are you missing.

Comment: @jcesarmobile i have updated the question, files are similar as the linked answer in the question because I followed that answer to create such structure.