# Generate an AAR file from Ionic Project

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, aar

Does anyone know how to generate an AAR file from an existing Ionic Project using the Cordova plugin? I know how to do it in Native Android, I don't know how to do it in Ionic.

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757208/cordova-plugin-development-adding-aar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cordova plugin development - adding aar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30757208/cordova-plugin-development-adding-aar)

Comment: Do you get to know how to generate an aar file from Ionic project?